# Can a gsm modem be integrated with the web server?

Tags: webserver, gsm, modem

I m doing a project for sending messages to various users at the same time.m using gsm modem for doing this service.I want to know whether a gsm modem can be integarted with the web server?how and what web server i can use?

Answer (score 0):

A GSM modem is a piece of hardware. A webserver is a piece of software that usually runs on a general purpose server computer. You might be able to install a GSM modem in the same server that runs your web server, but you would only want to do this in minimal applications such as embedded systems.

If you want to send text messages or otherwise communicate over the GSM network, you will probably be better off working with some sort of telecom gateway.